# database of Animals/insects which would contain their queriable geographic location?

Tags: zoology, entomology, database

Is there a database of Animals/insects which would contain their queriable geographic location?

I would need to perform a rather simple query, such as `Animals of <Location>`, where Location is some well-defined geographic area such as Elephant Nature Park - Thailand.

So far I have found multiple lists on Wikipedia and other webpages, however they seem to be quite incomplete as their intersect is quite small. Moreover, I have found EOL (Encyclopedia of Life) collections but they appear to struggle the same way.